# Having trouble connecting Android device for Eclipse development

Tags: android, driver

I'm running Windows 7, trying to connect my Android phone by USB so I can start developing in Eclipse.  The phone is a Huawei Prism running Android version 2.3.6, and I've set it to USB debug mode.  The phone's driver failed to install and I got the following error message:

```
Device driver software was not successfully installed
Android Adapter                      No driver found
```

I Googled around but couldn't find anything on this error.  The Device Manager shows a yellow exclamation point.

I'm not sure if this is a device usage question or a development question.  My goal is to get my phone to be available under Run As... in Eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must always install your specific phone USB Driver before being able to debug by USB.

So generally a " USB driver" search on Google does work.

I did it for you and found this page : http://www.huaweidevice.com/worldwide/downloadCenter.do?method=toDownloadFile&flay=software&softid=Mzk1MzA=

Is it the driver you tried ?

Answer (score 4):

Download and install Hi Suite. It's used for syncing Huawei devices, it'll have the driver you need.

http://www.huaweidevice.com/resource/mini/201105239635/hi_suite_en/

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. After installing this program it will automatically allow you to connect via ADB after accepting the PC on your device.

Answer (score 3):

A more flexible way is to install the Adb Driver Installer: http://adbdriver.com/downloads/

Once you download it, enable USB debugging on your phone and plug it to your computer. Then, use the Adb Driver Installer to install the required driver. It works for any Android device! Hope this was helpful. :)

Answer (score 1):

I recently found the right way to address this USB issue with Huawei.

1. Go to http://consumer.huawei.com/en/?method=toDownloadFile&flay=software&softid=Mzk1MzA=
2. Search: USB Driver
3. It will be the option HUAWEI Android Phones USB Driver
4. Make sure it is version v1[1].0 and file size 7.76 MB
5. Download zip, extract, proceed with usb download

Note: Make sure you debug and keep "stay awake" on before hooking up your device.

Comment: Up to date link: http://consumer.huawei.com/en/support/downloads/detail/index.htm?id=11802